# Error message 'adc' is an undeclared namespace

Tags: xslt-2.0, xml-namespaces

All, am im relatively new to XSLT but did some solutions allready. Currently i am trying to write an xslt that moves a file to different folders based on if

```
<adc:Status>uploaded</adc:Status>
```

is "uploaded" or not.

Despite declasring the xmlns:adc Namespace i get the error

> Exception Occured during TransForm using XSLT 2.0 (SaxonHe):
>   System.Xml.XmlException: 'adc' is an undeclared namespace. Line 2,
>   position 4.

I spent hours looking for the error messages, trying to getmyself into namespaces, but currently i cant seem to find out whats the cause of the error.

This is the xslt i wrote

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:adc="http://www.ifra.com/adconnexion/#v2"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
exclude-result-prefixes="xs xsi adc">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="/">
            <xsl:variable name="Filename">
                <xsl:value-of select="replace(document-uri(.), '.*/', '')"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="/adc:adConnexion/adc:Requests/adc:AdOrder/adc:ProductionDetail/adc:Material/adc:Status='uploaded'">
                    <!-- Business case -->
                    <xsl:variable name="OutputFileName" select="concat('file:///C:\UPLOADED\',$Filename)"/>
                    <xsl:result-document href="{$OutputFileName}">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="current()"/>
                    </xsl:result-document>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <!-- Non Business case -->
                    <xsl:variable name="OutputFileName" select="concat('file:///C:\ELSE\',$Filename)"/>
                    <xsl:result-document href="{$OutputFileName}">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="current()"/>
                    </xsl:result-document>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The simplified inputfile is

```
<adc:adConnexion xmlns:adc="http://www.ifra.com/adconnexion/#v2">
  <adc:Requests>
    <adc:AdOrder messageClass="BusinessTransaction" messageID="FEA*" bookingID="1234" messageCode="AD-O">
      <adc:ProductionDetail>
        <adc:Material>
            <adc:Status>uploaded</adc:Status>
        </adc:Material>
    </adc:AdOrder>
  </adc:Requests>
</adc:adConnexion>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which tool gives that error message, or which code (C# or VB.NET) if you have written it yourself gives that error? Do you get the same error when you run Saxon HE from the command line with e.g. `Transform -s:your-input.xml -xsl:your-stylesheet.xsl`?

Comment: On a side note, I would suggest to use a forwards slash in URIs as the separator character e.g. instead of `'file:///C:\UPLOADED\'` use `'file:///C:/UPLOADED/'`

Comment: Thank you for the hint about atesting the file with SaxonHE itself. It runs wonderfully there, no error at all. So its probably only a problem with the tool that embeds SaxonHe!!